# Error with Confluent Schema REST proxy when trying to set an Avro schema

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to update an avro schema using the rest proxy API in Confluent.  I can do a GET with the following, and get a valid response:

http://mykafkahost.com:8081/subjects/avro-schema-for-value/versions/1

But when I try this: 
http://mykafkahost.com:8081/subjects/my-avro-schema-for-value/1

using either POST, PUT, or PATCH, I consistently get

`{"error_code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}`

Also tried 
http://mykafkahost.com:8081/subjects/my-avro-schema-for-value/versions/1 
but it yields:

`{"error_code":405,"message":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}`

I've asked the operations team, and they don't believe specific verbs are enabled/disabled, but it's looking possible to me. If I need to enable the POST, what config file is this done through?

Answer (score 1):

> using the rest proxy API in Confluent

This is the **Schema Registry**, not the REST Proxy.

---

---

> But when I try this: `:8081/subjects/my-avro-schema-for-value/1`
>
> using either `POST, PUT, or PATCH`, I consistently get
>
> `{"error_code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}`

1. Typo? You put `/my-avro-schema`, not `/avro-schema`
2. [That address doesn't respond to those methods](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html#schemaregistry-api). Only **DELETE** works at `/subjects/<name>-value/versions/<version>`

> what config file is this done through?

There is only one config file for the Schema Registry.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to update the schema which is already registered in schema registry then here is the POST call,

```
HTTP POST:
URL http://mykafkahost.com:8081/subjects/my-avro-schema-for-value/ 
Post Body:
    {
          "schema":
             "{
                    \"type\": \"record\",
                    \"name\": \"test\",
                    \"fields\":
                      [
                        {
                          \"type\": \"string\",
                          \"name\": \"field1\"
                        },
                        {
                          \"type\": \"int\",
                          \"name\": \"field2\"
                        }
                      ]
                  }"
        }

Response: 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{"id":2}
```

On success of POST request, there will be a new version of the schema for the topic, but you can't update the existing version, you can only delete the version.

Hope this answers.